# shortening a .txt location to read it with scanner?

Tags: java, function

For a class project I had to read a `.txt` file with scanner, had it work perfectly. The only thing my professor wasn't happy about was the fact that my code hardcoded the path to the `.txt` file, for example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Users/Me/Documents/Programming/code.txt"));
```

That means it will only read the file if it's located in that exact folder. Anyways, what I wanted to know is how do I make the Scanner search for my documents and read the file, without having it in that exact folder, making it look something like this?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("code.txt"));
```

I heard it was something like adding a `"\"` to the .txt file name, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: Either way, `code.txt` will have to exist in a specific location. For your first example it has to be at that relative path, in your second example, it has to be in the working directory. Maybe your professor wanted you to allow the user to input the location of the file?

Comment: @Jeffrey Maybe he wants `%UserProfile%` which resolves to current user's home directory.

Comment: I'm not so sure of what he actually meant, but, having "code.txt" in scanner will read it no matter where it's located?

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek No. Having just `"code.txt"` will have the `Scanner` look for the file in the current working directory.

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek Then you should take the absolute path as input.

Comment: Ok, but do you know how do I make scanner search in every directory where it might be? And sorry for noobie questions haha

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek You need to have the user provide some sort of input. Searching every directory for a single file will take a long, long time. What would you do in the event that searching the *entire* hard drive turned up multiple files with the same name?

Comment: Nevermind haha, i'll just hand the project in in a pendrive, that way the file will simply be there. Thank you all anyways

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek - in short, doing a search would be a BAD idea in a real-world program.  I suggest you go back to your professor and ask him what he really meant.

Comment: @StephenC yeah, that's what I thought, but anyways, thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 2):

I think your professor was driving at an idea of passing *command line arguments* to your Java program. Remember the `String[] args` in the signature of `static void main`? That's the mechanism that he probably would like you to use, because it is the most flexible one.

Since you can pass any number of strings to your program on the command line, you can make a convention that the first argument will be the name of the file the user wants your program to open.

```
static public void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.err.println("Please pass a file name argument.");
        return;
    }
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    // ... do something useful
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, although I think this is a beat ahead of what I know, and I'm not currently allowed to use any static method or program inside the main

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek If you post how your `main` looks, I think we could provide some good suggestions on how to make use of command line arguments.

Comment: *"not currently allowed to use any static method or program inside the main"* If the 1st were true, you could not use a main (the main method has to be static).

Answer (score 1):

"code.txt" will work fine as long as code.txt is in the same directory.

Otherwise "../code.txt" takes you to the previous directory, and so on.

Comment: Will it work even if it's in any part of the hard drive? Because I have to hand in the project and obviously my professor's folders and locations are different than mine

Comment: "No such file or directory" :/

Comment: The file does have to be in the specified folder (so, "coder.txt" means it should be in the same file and "../coder.txt" should be in the upper level directory)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really want your program to search for a file name and get it please adapt one of the answers from here.

[Search recursively in text files in a directory with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455383/search-recursively-in-text-files-in-a-directory-with-java)

You can give a location to search and then recursively look at all the files till you get the file name you want. Then do whatever you want with the file. Also take a look at  [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) if you are allowed to use Swing components.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Java application, try

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

and supply the file name as the first command line argument.

This only works, of course, if the scanner is created in your `main` method, etc.  You should also check `args.length` to make sure the argument is present, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, although I think this is a beat ahead of what I know, and I'm not currently allowed to use any static method or program inside the main method

Comment: Ummm ... Ray is not suggesting that you "use [a] static method or program inside the main method".

Answer (score 0):

1. If this text file is specified at run-time, read it from the arguments array supplied to the main.
2. If it is an embedded (constant) application resource, gain an URL to it using something like:

---

```
URL urlToInput = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/code.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm pretty sure the following is what your professor wanted as I was assigned the very same task by mine.

Instead of passing an instance of `File` containing the file name into `Scanner`, why not just read in the file name using `Scanner`, create a seperate instance of `File` and pass it the file name read by `Scanner`?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = input.nextLine();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

The user will still be responsible for providing the full path of the file, but at least now it's whatever the user inputs and it's not hardcoded into the program as you have it displayed in your example.

I'm pretty sure this is how your professor *meant* for you to write this program.